# Cassandra clusters separation

Tags: cassandra

I have one single-node cluster and just added a multi-node cluster (on 4 seprate nodes, let's call them node1, node2,.., node4). The single-node cluster uses the localhost as seed_provider. The multi-node uses node1,node2 hosts as seeds  (SimpleSeedProvider).

To my suprise when I started the multi-node cluster I was able to see they started talking to the single-node Cassandra and they downloaded data from it.

How to prevent the new cluster talking to the existing cluster? Do I miss anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will "gossip" on the network and detect each other if they are not separated.

Did you make sure your `cluster_name` value in your `cassandra.yaml` file is not the same for both of your clusters? That's how they differentiate each other as said in the sample configuration file :

```
# The name of the cluster. This is mainly used to prevent machines in
# one logical cluster from joining another.
```

Comment: I changed the cluster names and indeed they do not download the data anymore but then we had some other issues - such as suddenly we started running out of open handlers on the servers. So you think as long as the cluster names are separate it will be ok? Is there any way to stop them "gossiping" to each other?

Comment: That's the whole point, you want them to gossip. Changing the cluster name makes them see they don't belong to each other. The only other way is to put them on separate networks. Although I doubt your handler issue is coming from the different names. I would clean my installation (remove the data, saved-caches and commitlog directories in the cassandra folder) on the new cluster if you don't have data that you don't want to lose on it yet, and restart it.